# How to connect from a VMware guest machine to the server installed on a Windows 7 host machine?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

How to connect from a VMware guest (virtual) machine to the server installed on the host (physical) machine? Things like typing "localhost" in the address bar of a browser in a guest machine don't work. My host machine's OS is Windows 7 64 bit with WMware Workstation installed on it, if it matters.

EDIT: The Bridged network connection in combination with referring to 192.168.0.10* from the guest machine did work (replace * with a digit starting from 0 until it works).

Comment: Ok, the question in the edit did not matter much, so removed. And it was Bridged not NAT that actually worked. Thanks a bunch to everyone for the answers.

Comment: How about, can I ask, in the reverse way: I set up a server on the guest machine, and I want to connect to the server on guest machine from the host computer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use "Bridged" Network Connection (see Virtual Machine Settings: Network Adapter), your VM will be given an IP address on the same LAN as your host machine. At that point, you can just HTTP to your host's IP address, eg. `http://192.168.0.100`

You can also do that with the other options, but with NAT and Host-only (if I recall correctly) your host machine will appear to your guest machine to have a different IP address than its real LAN address. So Bridged is the easiest and is likely your best bet, unless you have some specific needs.

Comment: this isnt working for me, i guess my corporate network is refusing to give out an ip address because it doesnt recognise the mac, or some other nac mechanism..

Comment: With the free version of VMWare, you cannot!  Use VirtualBox instead.  it's free.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do: Check that you have the network up and running. Try to ping the host system or any web site from the console of the guest OS, let's say `ping www.google.com`.

If you received any answers then please try writing the IP number of the host machine in the addressbar of the browser on the guest machine (NOT localhost :P). You should be able to see any web service running (Tip: Open the console of your windows 7 and type `ipconfig`, then find the ethernet adapter corresponding to VMWare and you'll find the IP number of your host system).

If you didn't received any answer at all when you did `ping` then check the network configuration of VMWare to use Bridged Connection --at least that's how it works for me.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In a guest machine, `localhost` refers to the virtual machine itself.  Refer to the host just as you would from any other machine: by its IP address.

Note that it may be using a second "virtual" network adapter to communicate with the guest.  Check the VMware to find out, and to find the second IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same IP sub net for your VMware machine, if your windows system has ip address class C  192.168.0.10  So assign 192.168.0.120 IP to your Vmware machine and make sure that Firewall allow the traffic in vmware and also add the listener port manually in vm machine.  go to system - administration- firwal-add port 1521.

Thanks